# If $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu$ is finite, does it implies that $\nu$ is also finite?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two (positive) measures, where $\mu$ is finite. Is it true that
if $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu$ is finite, does it imply that $\nu$ is also finite? If so, how does one prove it? If not, what is a counter-example?

Comment: The measure $\mu$ on the power set of $\{1\}$ defined as $\mu(x)=0$ iff $x=\emptyset$ and $\infty$ otherwise and $\nu$ the counting measure satisfy $\mu\ll \nu$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $((0,1),m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\nu(dx)=\frac{1}{x}m(dx)$ for a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance Lebesgue measure is absolute-continuously equivalent to $$\mu(\bullet)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int 1_\bullet(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$$

(its density being $\sqrt{2\pi}e^{x^2/2}$). More generally, any non-zero $\sigma$-finite measure is absolute-continuously equivalent to a probability.

Comment: @joshua In your notation, I provided an example where $\mu\ll m$ and $m\ll \mu$ (that is what I mean by two measures being absolute-continuously equivalent).